# LocalNotifications will start 3 days earlier and stop when reach the spesific day

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uilocalnotification

I setup a LocalNotification. User will enter his bill last pay day.And I have to notify him 3 days earlier and it should continue until payday == today.

3 days earlier notification is working now with those codes and it can repeat itself daily.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
         NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
         [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];
         NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

         [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
         [components setHour:12];
         [components setMinute:00];
         [components setDay: faturaSonOdemeGunuNumber.integerValue -3];

         NSDate *test = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


         // Schedule the notification
         UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

         if (localNotification == nil)return;

         localNotification.fireDate = test;
         localNotification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtFaturaAdi.text,@"SilenecekNotification", nil];
         localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 3 days left.",_txtFaturaAdi.text];
         localNotification.alertAction = @"Faturayı göster";
         localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
         localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
         localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
         localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
```

faturaSonOdemeGunuNumber means user lastpayday...

But, I couldn't find **How to stop this notification when user lastpayday == today ???**

Can someone help me to solve this problem Please ?